# Can I get attach_file to work without an ID or class name?

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara

The markup looks exactly like this:

`<input type="file">`

Is there any way to get `attach_file` to work with this?

In the meantime I've asked a dev to add an id for me, but I try to avoid any special asks altogether.

Comment: Are you asking for an XPath?  I'm not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: As far as I know, attach_file requires an ID when using it.  Doing something like `attach_file('input[type="file"], 'file.txt')` will not work.  I'm asking if there is a way to use attach_file with the given markup that I provided.

Comment: I have asked our devs to update the markup to appear like `<input type="file" id="upload">` and that works fine when using `upload` as an id.  I'd like to avoid asking devs to make changes to accommodate my specs so it would be great to know if I can use attach_file the way the markup was before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybara's `#attach_field` basically boils down to `find(:file_field, locator, options).set(path)` which will find by id, name, or associated label text.  However if you find the element another way you can just call `#set` on it with the path.  Another thing to note is that (with up to date  versions of Capybara) if you only have one file field on the page or you are scoped to a region of the page that only has one file field you can pass `nil` as the locator and it will just find any input of type 'file'.

So

```
attach_file(nil, 'test.txt')
```

is equivalent to

```
find('input[type="file"]').set('text.txt')
```

except that the example with `set` will skip Capybara's existence test for the file

Comment: @Phil FYI You can pass nil (or just leave out the locator) to most of the specific selectors (:field, :checkbox, :radio_button, etc) and actions if there is only one matching element in the current scope.  The `attach_file` method is one use  where the `nil` is currently required, but that requirement will probably be gone in the next version of Capybara.

Comment: Thanks, Tom I'll keep that in mind.  That's good to know about the specific selectors.